# Highcharts: smooth adding point to line chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with Highcharts, and I am trying to implement very smooth line chart, that will stream the data that I fetch from a server. So far, the data comes every second, and there is a small lag in displaying the values. I am adding the values as follows:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint(newPoint), false, true);
chart.redraw();
```

and as animation I use:

```
animation: Highcharts.svg
```

I would like the transition to be as smooth as those graphs here:

http://smoothiecharts.org/examples/server-load.html

Any ideas?

Thank
-uksz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use animate while add point as below

```
chart.series[0].addPoint(newPoint,true, true, animate)
```

also check, are you setting any time for animate function and its calling at update or not.

Comment: What should I put as animate value?

Comment: @uksz See API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint _Defaults to true. When true, the graph will be animated with default animation options. The animation can also be a configuration object with properties duration and easing._